# High resolution bitmap quality issue

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

I get bitmap from drawable but bitmap sized is maximum 1024*1024..i will try to get
bitmap full resolution from drawable but ican't get.I will try to all possibile work but not get how to solve this problem.I try to last 4 days but not get any proper solution.I want to need get full resolution bitmap from drawable

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = drawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 1025, 1025, false);
```

Comment: If image is in drawable folder why not use `BitmapFactory#decodeResource()`.?

Comment: simply use 
Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_image);

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put your image file in drawable-nodpi. nodpi will not resize your drawable.

Second, you can use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_pop);` to retrieve Bitmap from resource.

**Edit-**

You can use 'inScaled' options when retrieving Bitmap from the resource. I checked from my project. (original image size is 1920x1080

```
val options= BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inScaled = false
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.splatoon, options)
```

[ScreenShot, in imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OsZx.jpg)

Comment: I tried all possible changes but not work.I already put images into drawable-nodpi and My images resolution is 1082*1673 But when i get using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_pop) bitmap resolution can not get perfectly evary time image resolution is 673*1024 Why?

Comment: Have you tried android:scaleType in your ImageView. How are you adding the it to ImageView can you paste your layout xml.

Comment: <ImageView

       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:id="@+id/img"
       android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: @JigarPatelVisnagar I edited my answer. check it out.

Comment: Thanks @WindSekirun ... i Seen bitmap width and height into logcat which is perfectly  but my bitmap image is not perfectly got....Please Check this my two Url which url is

[1]. https://pasteboard.co/I2MQURBz.png
[2]. https://pasteboard.co/I2MT1Tn.png

Please Chek this

Comment: @JigarPatelVisnagar That feature is **a debugging feature on Android Studio, not Android runtime**. So you can use origin image with 'inScaled' options. You can ignore the second screenshot. If Bitmap's width and height are correct, the Bitmap is an origin.

Comment: Thanks @WindSekirun   But My bitmap resolution was starch..So the pixel of image stretch..Generally my images mostly used into color fill app.If my pixel was streach then i can't fill color into bitmap

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand  your 'stretch' means. I think your purpose is using origin as background of activity. If yes, try use centerInside option in ScaleType of ImageView.

Comment: stretching means images width are large and every pixel of images are damaged

Comment: Can you give project code or screenshot? that is too abstract.